# Visual Studio - how to set a breakpoint in .NET source code (core libraray, not my code)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a C# .NET5 web app project, using newest Visual Studio. From the debug output I found out that an exception is thrown in .NET source code: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Antiforgery/src/Internal/DefaultAntiforgery.cs

I'd like to set a breakpoint in this code. I note that Visual Studio downloaded the corresponding PDB file, but I have no idea how to set the breakpoint...?

I'm adding a screenshot of my debug settings.[image]

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473

Comment: This solution requires 10 GB of space, several prerequisites for compilation and compiling the whole .NET! And when VS installs a newer version of .NET I have to do it all again...